# How to store the long hexadecimal number in scalar and print in back in perl

Tags: perl, variables

```
$hexnumber = 0x09C343C2E95ACABA;
print ("$hexnumber");
```

I am getting printed response as `703480471217687226`. Can any one help me in solving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

That's expected. What's your question? If you turn on warnings you will notice below warning:

```
Hexadecimal number > 0xffffffff non-portable at test.pl line 4.
```

You may use bigint pragma which replaces the hex function with a version that can handle numbers that large.

```
use bigint qw/hex/;
```

> hex
>
> Override the built-in hex() method with a version that can handle
>   big integers. This overrides it by exporting it to the current
>   package. Under Perl v5.10.0 and higher, this is not so necessary, as
>   hex() is lexically overridden in the current scope whenever the bigint
>   pragma is active. -[perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/bigint.html)

Comment: you should show an example of *using* the hex function too

Answer (score 1):

You can print out numbers in hexidecimal using printf:

```
printf "%X", $hexnumber;  # or %x for lower case a-f digits
```

but note that this isn't portable to perls that use 32-bit integers.
Perhaps you really just want to store it as a string in the first place?

Comment: Yes you are correct , if i want to store the hexadecimal number in a variable and want t retrieve back in the same form i need to store as sting initially... I understood now thank you.